# What is the difference between DMA-Engine and DMA-Controller?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dma

1. As mentioned above, what is the difference between a dma engine and a dma-controller (on focus on linux)?
2. When does the linux dma engine come into place? Is this a special device or always part of all periphery devices, which support dma?
3. When browsing the linux source, I found the driver ste_dma40.c. How does any driver uses this engine?

Comment: 1. Are you talking about hardware IPs or Linux terms? 2. Same question. 3. It's being used via `DMAengine framework`. Just read *Documentation/dmaengine/* for more information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DMA - Direct memory access. The operation of your driver reading or writing from/to your HW memory without the CPU being involved in it (freeing it to do other stuff).

DMA Controller - reading and writing can't be done by magic. if the CPU doesn't do it, we need another HW to do it. Many years ago (at the time of ISA/EISA) it was common to use a shared HW on the motherboard that did this operation. In recent years , each HW has its own DMA HW mechanism. 
But in all cases this specific HW gets the source address and the destination address and passes the data. Usually triggering an interrupt when done.

DMA Engine - Now here I am not sure what you mean. I believe you probably refer to the SW side that handles the DMA.
DMA is a little more complicated than usual I\O since all memory SRC and DST has to be physically present at all times during the DMA operation. If the DST address is swapped to disk, the HW will write to a bad address and the system will crash.
This and other aspects of DMA are handled by the driver with code sections you probably refer to as the "DMA Engine"

*Another interpretation of what 'DMA Engine' is, may be a code part of Firmware (or HW) that handles the DMA HW controller on the HW side.

Comment: *"If the DST address is swapped to disk, the HW will write to a bad address and the system will crash."* --  Such a *"bad address"* would only be if virtual memory was involved.   The more common DMAC uses physical memory addresses, which cannot go *"bad"*.  Otherwise this issue is avoided by simply requiring the memory region to be locked down, i.e. the virtual-to-physical memory mapping cannot be changed during the DMA operation.

Answer (score 3):

According to this document, http://www.asprom.com/application/intel_3.pdf:

The 82C37 DMA controllers should not
be confused with the DMA engines found
in some earlier MCH (Memory Controller
Hub) components. These DMA controllers
are tied to the ISA/LPC bus and used
mostly for transfers to/from slow
devices such as floppy disk controllers.

So it seems it is  a device found on previous platfroms that used MCHs devices.